# Time out exception with WebDriverWait despite faster internet and element present

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape this:
https://www.lanebryant.com/chiffon-faux-wrap-fit-flare-midi-dress/prd-355958#color/0000091393

And this is my code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(d, 10)
close = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='closeButton']")))
close.click()
time.sleep(5)
chart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(*,'Size Guide')][@class='size-chart-link']")))
chart.click()
```

It first closes the pop up and then clicks the size guide, However, it always gives timeout exception and works only a couple of times.

Comment: maybe "EC" is not defined?  Did you import ExpectedConditions as "EC"?

Answer (score 1):

The `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT` **Size Guide** is pretty much **unique** within the page so would be your best bet would be to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for `invisibility_of_element()` for the wrapper element
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` for the desired element
- You can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Code Block (using XPATH and PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT):

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.lanebryant.com/chiffon-faux-wrap-fit-flare-midi-dress/prd-355958#color/0000091393')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='closeButton']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='tinymask']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Size Guide"))).click()
    ```
  - Code Block (using CSS_SELECTOR and PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT):

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.lanebryant.com/chiffon-faux-wrap-fit-flare-midi-dress/prd-355958#color/0000091393')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#closeButton"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#tinymask")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Size Guide"))).click()
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Size Guide]

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript Executor to click on the element.Seems like selenium webdriver unable to click on the element.Use the below xpath

```
d.get("https://www.lanebryant.com/chiffon-faux-wrap-fit-flare-midi-dress/prd-355958#color/0000091393")

wait = WebDriverWait(d, 10)
close = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='closeButton']")))
close.click()
chart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='size-chart-link']/a[contains(.,'Size Guide')]")))
d.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", chart)
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work gives this:  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='size-chart-link']/a[contains(.,'Size Guide')]")))
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: Strange!!! I am able to click with that code.see browser snapshot i have attached.

Comment: I am using it with Scrapy. would that be causing the issue?

Comment: Possibly. Because  I am using chrome browser.which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome driver 75

Comment: strange!!! on my machine I have chrome driver 74 and chrome browser 74 as well.I am still confuse why this is not working for you.

Comment: However I do not have much knowledge about Scrapy though.

Comment: Is there any other way I can get values inside the table?(without clicking)